# Particle in a double delta potential, scatter states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering

I was studying the scatter states of a particle in a double delta potential given in this link:

[Double delta function well – scattering states](http://www.physicspages.com/2012/08/02/double-delta-function-well-scattering-states/)

But I dont understand how equations (20) and (21) were obtained, any one of the equation is sufficient actually, the other can be obtained.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question formulation self-contained, so one doesn't have to open the link to understand the question.

Comment: Courage, your link is now dead, providing a good example of another reason why we insist on the site for the questions to be self-contained. I found [this pdf](http://physicspages.com/pdf/Quantum%20mechanics/Delta-function%20well%20-%20scattering.pdf), but I'm not sure whether the equation numbering corresponds to your original source - could you please check that update the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution considers waves propagating in the positive $x$ direction, since for $x>a$ the wave function is $\psi(x) = F e^{ikx}$. Accordingly, the internal transmission rate for the internal segment $-a \le x \le a$ is given by the relative amplitude of the $e^{ikx}$ component, the one "transmitted" in the same direction as the outgoing wave. Similarly, the reflection coefficient is given by the "reflected" $e^{-ikx}$ component propagating in the opposite direction. Since in the inner region $\psi(x) = C e^{ikx} + D e^{-ikx}$, where both $C$ and $D$ are proportional to $A$, this gives $T_i = |C|^2/|A|^2$ and $R_i = |D|^2/|A|^2$, with $C$ and $D$ as in Eqs.(11), (12).